# How to handling login redirects back to app from multiple social login accounts swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, twitter, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am making an app that allows user to login from different platforms such as google, Facebook , twitter etc. In the App delegate we have to implement a function application:openURL:options: for each of the platforms. 
Currently my function looks like this.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    // Todo handle based on the the arguments and return the bool value to be checked on iPHONE with facebook, google and twitter app
    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])

    Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

    return handled
}
```

As seen above I am returning handled that is the Facebook's redirect handle result. Google and twitter returns a bool value too. 
What is the safest and correct way to return handle bool value of Facebook, google and twitter for the above function?

Comment: Don’t you know which type of login the user was attempting?  Set a variable before you attempt the login and check it when control returns to this function in order to know what sort of result you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this approach

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

     let facebookDidHandle = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

     let googleDidhandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])

     let twitterDidHandle = Twitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)


     return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle || twitterDidHandle
}
```